# Understanding sync.cond in golang

Tags: go, asynchronous, concurrency

I have started learning golang recently and I came across this sync.Cond function. I have little trouble understanding how this works.

consider the below code

```
var sharedRsc = make(map[string]interface{})

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    mu := sync.Mutex{}
    c := sync.NewCond(&mu)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        c.L.Lock()
        // for len(sharedRsc) == 0 {
        c.Wait()
        // }

        c.L.Unlock()
        fmt.Println(sharedRsc["rsc1"])
    }()

    // writes changes to sharedRsc
    c.L.Lock()
    sharedRsc["rsc1"] = "foo"
    c.Signal()
    c.L.Unlock()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

when this is executed it leads to a deadlock. I understand the reason might be c.Signal is called before c.Wait.

But what I don't understand is when we uncomment the for loop it works. So how does the for loop solves this race condition? Even here there is a possibility c.Signal can be called before c.Wait right?

Comment: haha, yeah. sync.cond is one thing in go i always have trouble with. i made it work once, or at least i hope it worked, and never used it anywhere because i just don't get it. don' believe it. don't trust i got it right. so i refactor code to not needed it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the for loop because if the cond is signaled before the second coroutine waiting, it will deadlock at the Wait() because no one will signal after that.

Consider the following execution flow:

- Modify `sharedRsc`
- c.Signal()
- wg.Wait()
- c.Wait()

Comment: I understand that how does the for loop solves this race condition. Even with the for loop what will happen if the c.Signal is called before c.Wait ??

Comment: If c.Signal() is called before c.Wait(), nothing happens and c.Wait() will block until the next signal (which never arrives). If there is a for loop, the Wait() won't be called because the resource is available, there is no more need to wait.

Comment: No, I understand that. Consider the scenario. Even with the for loop, there is a possibility that c.signal can be called before c.wait right ??.

All the for loop checks is if the length of the map is 0 it goes into wait.

Comment: @Kannan.dev, but c.Signal() will only be called when you have the resource.

Comment: Got it now i understand, But why that should be a for loop why not a simple if condition ?

Answer (score -1):

This is how to correctly use `sync.Cond`.

You do not really need `sync.Cond` if you have one goroutine for each write and read - a single `sync.Mutex` would suffice to communicate between them. `sync.Cond` could useful in situations where multiple readers wait for the shared resources to be available.

```
var sharedRsc = make(map[string]interface{})
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    m := sync.Mutex{}
    c := sync.NewCond(&m)
    go func() {
        // this go routine wait for changes to the sharedRsc
        c.L.Lock()
        for len(sharedRsc) == 0 {
            c.Wait()
        }
        fmt.Println(sharedRsc["rsc1"])
        c.L.Unlock()
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        // this go routine wait for changes to the sharedRsc
        c.L.Lock()
        for len(sharedRsc) == 0 {
            c.Wait()
        }
        fmt.Println(sharedRsc["rsc2"])
        c.L.Unlock()
        wg.Done()
    }()

    // this one writes changes to sharedRsc
    c.L.Lock()
    sharedRsc["rsc1"] = "foo"
    sharedRsc["rsc2"] = "bar"
    c.Broadcast()
    c.L.Unlock()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

You can it in [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/K9YX_g5OqWD).

Using channels is still the recommended way to pass data around if the situation permitting.

Note: `sync.WaitGroup` here is only used to wait for the goroutines to complete their executions.

For better understanding refer the official docs : https://pkg.go.dev/sync

And also see the similar SO : [How to correctly use sync.Cond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857167/how-to-correctly-use-sync-cond)

Comment: One small problem, you are supposed to wait for the condition you are expecting, as such, `for len() == 0` wouldn't suffice...